# Can a subscriber be a publisher at same time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

I want to setup a topology for replication.

The scenario is such that a subscriber is subscribed to transaction replication based publisher (distributor running on publisher).

I then want this subscriber to be a publisher to another subscriber. I want the distributor to be on publisher instance (push).

Can some body help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve the goal and implement replication topology. What I understood from your requirements is depicted in the diagram.

[image]

To do this follow these steps:

1. Enable distribution on Server 1.
2. Create replication, add articles and choose server 1 as publisher and server 2 as subscriber.
3. Once articles are replicated, enable distribution on server 2.
4. Follow step 2 for servers 2 and 3.